# Try sin excepción en PHP

Tags: php, html, try-catch

Tengo una etiqueta `HTML` a la cual asigno el atributo `value` a un valor de `PHP` con un `try`. Mi código :

```
<input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nombre" 
  value="<?php try { echo $_SESSION['frm_nom']; } catch(Exception $e){} ?>">
```

Y me muestra el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gabinete\pred\peu.php on line 114

Comment: Cual es la linea 114 del archivo peu.php? Has intentado `catch (Exception $e) { ; }`

Comment: La linea 114 es el final del archivo

Comment: @GerryStudios el error que muestra no creo que sea en la línea expuesta del `input` , es en otra línea de su archivo `peu.php`

Comment: Entonces tu error no es del catch. Si tienes mas etiquetas php verifica que todas estèn bien cerradas con la llaves { . El error es por que probablemente se esperaba una expresión o un cierre, pero no se encontrò. Serìa  excelente si puede poner el fichero completo en php...

Comment: Ahora mismo no tengo el ordenador

Comment: Pero eso así... está raro raro. Yo haría el `try...` en un bloque PHP **fuera** del elemento HTML input y guardaría el dato en una variable. Ejemplo: `try { $sForm=$_SESSION['frm_nom']; } catch(Exception $e){$sForm="noName";} ` y luego en el input: `<input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nombre" 
  value="<?php echo $sForm ?>">`

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, me faltaba cerrar un bloque if. Gracias por haberme hecho fijar en el código entero